# Building a Wordpress powered bilingual website

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I am about to develop a bilingual website that will use a global language switch, exactly as  [this architectural website](http://www.zundelcristea.com), with the `FR|EN` switch.

Clicking on `FR` link should ideally lead me to `www.mydomain.com/fr/my_content`. The same behaviour is expacted with the `EN` one.

I have read the [Wordpress page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress) on the topic, and had a look at a few plugins. I am now looking for human feeback, ideally from someone who would have built something similar, before jumping right into it as the list of alternative is quite long.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55945/is-there-a-plugin-that-will-facilitate-displaying-a-website-static-pages-not-a/55992#55992

Comment: Why make the user pick their language?  You could do that, but I'd also suggest adding the language detection first... that way it most likely is correct first and the user can change if it's not. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=detect+language&sort=

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. 
I dive into them more thouroughly this weekend, and reach back to you.